# Ordered list inside table?

Tags: php, html

i'm have troubles filling my table, i want to generate a table by an array of elements and show it in a ordered list, but it shows an unordered list and idk why? i attach my code below, what's wrong? thank u for ur replies

```
<table align="left">
      <?php
      echo "<ol type='A'>";
        for ($i=0; $i < count($elements); $i++) {
          echo "<tr>
            <td>
              <li><h5><label for='opcion'>".implode(", ", $elements[$i])."</label></h5> </li>
            </td>
          </tr>";
        }
      echo "</ol>";
      ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Kindly used this format <ol><li><tr><td> ANY NAME </td></tr></li></ol>

Comment: @SyedNoman, OP is looking for an ordered list.

Comment: Move your tr and td tags outside you list

Comment: I tried that but it does not work, it seems that is not possible to put a ordered list inside a table, check the comment below =/

Answer (score 4):

A table can't have `ol` elements as children.  The entire list needs to be in a single `td` element, or outside of the table completely.

Comment: Oh I did not know that, then it is impossible to do that?